# Kubernetes deployment with at least two nodes used

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to deploy a Deployment to Kubernetes. It should have two properties

- If the replica count is above 2, it has to be on two different nodes (if just one node available ... scale the number of nodes up)
- If we have more than two replicas, say 3 or 4, it is not necessarily scaling up the nodes beyond two, but using them if available. Furthermore, we should try to make it as balanced over the nodes as possible.

This would be for a YAML file.

In addition, I am wondering how I can enforce the same behavior for the helm chart (https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx).

It would be great if you could help me here.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you need to read about `podAntiAffinity` within your Kubernetes manifests. This ensures that when you scale replicas, they will not schedule on a node where a pod of the same deployment (rather a pod that matches label criteria, usually) exists.